# DJI Windows SDK Sample - cannot view FPV mode

Tags: dji-sdk

I've cloned Windows SDK repo, open the sample solution with latest visual studio, fixed the dll ref for Windows SDK x86,
build the solution on x86 and activated the sample app with my key.

I've turned on WiFi mode on my DJI Mavic Air and connected my laptop to its WiFi, but nothing get displayed on the FPV screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks weird, Could you help to check the following steps?

1. Make sure your DJI Windows SDK Sample is updated to the latest version.
2. Make sure your Mavic Air is updated to the newest firmware version.
3. Try restarting the Mavic Air after switching it to Wi-Fi mode.
4. You could select the 'Component Handle' page of the sample app and try to get the name of the aircraft by which you could know if the SDK could get data from the aircraft successfully.

Also, you can check this documentation of running the sample code: https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/documentation/quick-start/index.html

If you still cannot see the FPV live video feed using the sample, please contact dev@dji.com for help.

Comment: Hi,

I have latest version both of DJI Windows SDK and Mavic Air firmware,
Suddenly (after rebooting the drone and my laptop) the connection was successful and I can now view FPV on my UWP, it's very strange because I did that many times, anyways it works now.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The exact order and timing of turning things on, connecting and running applications can be critical.